# Does Plopsaland De Panne have many rides that can fit taller adults?

Tags: family, belgium, amusement-parks

Earlier this year, my brother, his wife and their son (6yo) went to Plopsaland De Panne, in Belgium. I was invited to come along, but I checked the website and it looked like a lot of the rides were aimed at younger children and their parents, and a lot of them seemed like adults, especially taller ones like me (well over 6'/180cm) might not be comfortable in them. I was especially worried about cramped legroom and safety harnesses that don't fit properly.

I ended up not going anyway because I don't really like Studio 100 entertainment anyway, and I don't like being around kids that aren't my godson. But if I were to get invited again, to what extent are rides in the park able to handle taller adults that are almost twice the size of the average children that ride the rides?

Comment: What did your brother tell you, how he liked it?

Comment: I voted to close, as answers will be wholly opinion.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica Understood. I tried to make the question more about facts, i.e. to what extent are the rides able to handle taller adults. I feel like that is more objectively answerable than "are the rides enjoyable?".

Comment: @Nzall One person may be interested in (or tolerate) squeezing into a ride because, in their opinion, the squeeze is worth it to experience the ride. Thus, I still think it's opinion.

Comment: @DavidsupportsMonica I mean, yeah, but that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking about the physical capability of rides to safely contain taller riders. I'm not asking about whether that ride would actually be worth the squeeze. I'll judge that myself based on the provided information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm myself of average height (1,80m) but really overweight so this might not be the exact same situation but I surely understand the feeling.

It is true that Plopsa is aimed at younger kids in the sense that many of the attractions, including (small) rollercoasters, can accommodate kids from the size of 1m whereas other amusement parks in Belgium have only a few (if at all) sensation rides for the smaller ones (usually starting at 1,20m but very commonly 1,40m as soon as you have your head upside-down). That said, these attractions are not more or less comfortable for a tall person (or in my case, overweight) than any attraction in any other amusement park, I personally never had more problems there than other parks, the problem being generally the workers having to "push" on the bar for it to close correctly due to my womb.

Now I've seen (in other parks) attractions with a maximal height of 1,90m (usually), but I don't remember seeing one like that at Plopsa. Their website also doesn't seem to indicate any max size (I've tried and don't see any difference).

It's been 2 years now I didn't go there, so I might be wrong (especially as I'm not concerned I may have overlooked max size) and the site might not be correct on this , the only way to be sure would be to ask them directly. If you don't want to ask, I would say it is safe to assume you'll be able to fit any attraction in Plopsa with a variable level of comfort.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard as we don't know what attractions you like. This might be ice skating and the merry go-around or the big rollercoasters.
On the site of Plopsaland De Panne there's an overview of [the attractions](https://www.plopsalanddepanne.be/en/attractions?length=200) it has.

On the left you can see a slider to set how big you are and get an overview of the attractions you can get into. Which, as an adult will probably be everything.

Looking at the pictures of the attractions might suggest if it's build for adults. I see 2 rollercoasters that seem to have alot of leg space.

Comment: Note that sometimes it's not only about minimal size, it's also about maximal size. From what I know being >1,90 m usually means you're not allowed in any attraction where the security thing is around your head and above your shoulders.